# 80's anime about Vlad Tepes impaling bodies for his enemies to watch

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember seeing, at a friend's house, as a child in the late 80's (probably 1988 or 1989), an anime which talked about Vlad Tepes.

I'm not sure if it showed vampires at all, but I remember one particular scene, on which Vlad Tepes had impaled a lot of bodies for his enemies to watch.

I tried to research it, but Google's full of results mentioning *Hellsing*.

I recall it as an anime, but maybe my memories are off.

Comment: so its not the hellsing anime?\

Comment: It might be one of the items in the list at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracula_in_popular_culture#Anime_and_manga

Comment: @himarm Hellsing was first released in 1997, so that can't be it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could it be the 1980s adaptation of Marvel's *Tomb of Dracula*, entitled *[Dracula: Sovereign Of The Damned](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=3875)* in the United States?

> In contemporary Boston, Dracula gatecrashes a Satanic ritual and makes off with the intended sacrifice, Delores. Overcome with love for her, he's unable to drink her blood and instead settles down with her and fathers a child, Janus. But Dracula's enemies are massing against him - a team of vampire hunters, including the wheelchair-bound Hans Harker, crossbow wielding and new recruit Frank Drake, a descendant of Dracula, are closing in. And Dracula has been stripped of his vampire powers by Satan and he desperately needs another vampire to restore his powers so that he can both see off his pursuers and avenge the death of Janus at the hands of vengeful Satanists.

[image: Screenshot of Dracula about to hurt someone]

[image: One VHS cover]

The full film can be found on YouTube. You can see the impalement about 30 minutes in:

And [here's a review](https://comicsalliance.com/comicsalliance-vs-the-hilariously-terrible-tomb-of-dracula-an/) with a fair amount of the plot described.

Comment: I'll have to check, but everything seems accurate although I can't remember the two (main?) protagonists on the front of the cover.

Comment: There were a number of different covers. For example, this one just has Dracula: http://www.anime-games.co.uk/VHS/anime/dracula.php

Comment: Wow! I'm impressed! Your answer is correct, and you were quick! Many thanks for the YouTube link!